# Why tessellation is preferred over fragment displacement mapping?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader

I am an absolute newbie in computer graphics, so my question might have an obvious answer.

It seems like there exist approaches to getting nice self-occlusion effects using fragment displacement mapping, i.e. moving actual fragments (pixels) according to the highlight map in the direction of the normal and then drawing them so that the resulting z-order and occlusions work nicely together. Afaik, people were archiving it with multiple passes with distance clipping based on that resulting virtual distance computed using depth map, and mixing these multiple passes with some smoothing after that.

Here are several papers: [[1]](http://sirkan.iit.bme.hu/~szirmay/egdisfinal3.pdf), [[2]](http://download.nvidia.com/developer/GPU_Gems_2/GPU_Gems2_ch08.pdf), [[3]](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/Tatarchuk-ParallaxOcclusionMapping-FINAL_Print.pdf), [[4]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.6095&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

From a perspective of a person who is completely new to the field, this seems way more efficient and should work with any level of details without any performance issues, compared to inflating the number of vertexes in runtime the way tessellation does that, as far as I understand that.

But people still seem to favor tessellation - why?

**UPD**: After talking to some graphics people, the answer seems to be "because tessellation is specifically hardware accelerated on modern GPUs, whereas displacement shaders are essentially a hack".

Comment: I am *not* a CG expert and I'm curious what answers come from people who know. I know you *do* see parallel occlusion mapping in practice, which looked closely related to that first paper you linked to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gBAOB7b5Mg. They give some impressive examples and go over some of the limitations -- shader cost is one, artifacts in some extreme situations are another. Also seems like a factor that fixed-function hardware for rendering geometry is plentiful and optimized on modern GPUs--those extra polys may be cheaper than they seem.

Comment: Incidentally, it's not responsive to your question but http://apoorvaj.io/exploring-bump-mapping-with-webgl.html has a great demo of basic POM rendering with source.

Comment: @twotwo these are some cool resources! Now I am confused about how parallax occlusion mapping is different from fragment displacement mapping I mentioned above :)

Comment: (Also, that technique is *parallax* occlusion mapping, not parallel, for the record/for findability. Whoops.)